Help identify this desert war movie
I saw this movie about 10 years ago in Guatemala the movie was in Spanish but I'm not sure if it was dubbed or that was the original. The movie is about a group of soldiers in the desert, they are very low on supplies I believe they had a tank or vehicle of some sort which I think one of the soldiers hides under at one point in the movie. Also at one point they find a dried up well and they send someone down where there is a small drip to collect in a metal tin. Near the end of the movie the group makes it to a fort in the desert where they defend against the enemy. I know for certain stick grenades were used so I'm thinking the enemy was the Germans but I'm unsure if it was in WWII or WWI. 
I hope this is enough information sorry that I can't remember more.

Possibly Sahara, a 1995 TV movie from Australia and the USA, starring Jim Belushi and Michael Massee. It is set in 1942:
Plot synopsis:

After the fall of Tobruk in June 1942, U.S. Army sergeant Joe Gunn leads his tank into the Sahara desert, in order to evade advancing Rommel's forces and reach Allied lines. Along the way he picks up few Allied soldiers, but soon they are running out of water. They find water at the ancient well, but the well is a goal of an entire German battalion. Despite the impossible odds, Sergeant Gunn decides to defend the well.

The tank (M3 Lee), according to Wikipedia:

The movie:



